# Known insecure IoT devices

Tags: protocols, internet

I would like to create my own twist on intelligent home using various IoT devices. My goal is to try and pentest said devices in real-life-like scenerios. I'd like to cover various popular protocols used in IoT (ZigBee, Z-Wave, WiFi, Bluetooth 4/4.2) and convieniances as user-/device-facing Cloud, automatic updates, out-of-the-box auto-configuration, smartphone and web apps. [Usual OWASP Top 10 stuff](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Internet_of_Things_Top_Ten_Project)

How would you go about choosing them? Is there any online resource that could be used as source (of critique)?

I found few ideas watching DEFCON, BLACK HAT and other conferences. I also tried using Amazon reviews and googling (obviously).

Bonus question: If there is no online resource comprehensive enough for IoT devices end-users, what do you think about making one?

Comment: Any proprietary/homebrew protocol would be definitely unsafe as companies who develop them usually don't bother investing in proper security, so you may want to look at such devices first.